# Is there a pythonic way to log a function with extra values without bloating its paramter list?

Tags: python, logging, functional-programming

I am currently struggling to log a function in python in a clean way.

Assume I want to log a function which has an obscure `list_of_numbers` as argument.

```py
def function_to_log(list_of_numbers):
    
   # manipulate the values in list_of_numbers ...
   
   return some_result_computed_from_list_of_numbers
```

When the values in `list_of_numbers` are manipulated in the above function, I would like to log that change, but not with the value in the obscure `list_of_numbers`, but the value at the same index in a second list `list_with_names_for_log`.

The thing that annoys me: now I also have to input `list_with_names_for_log`, which bloats the argument list of my function,

```py
def function_to_log(list_of_numbers, list_with_names_for_log):

    # do some stuff like, change value on 3rd index:
    list_of_numbers[3] = 17.4
    log.info('You have changed {} to 17.4'.format(list_with_names_for_log[3]))
    # and so on ...

    return some_result_computed_from_list_of_numbers
```

I use multiple of these lists exclusively for logging in this function.
Has anybody an idea how to get this a little bit cleaner?

Comment: Are the lists that can be used for the `list_with_names_for_log` argument in the same scope as the function? How does the calling expression decide which list to use?

Comment: Yep, the lists reside in a mother function that calls `function_to_log` with them as extra arguments.
Which list to use is hard coded in `function_to_log`: for some manipulations I just use one `list_with_names` for logging, for some manipulations a combination of these lists.

Comment: Probably not enough detail in your question to provide an adequate solution for your circumstance. As Carcigenicate points out you have pairs of lists that are associated by their index so Carcigenicate's solution might solve your problem of having an unwanted *extra* function parameter. If there is a relationship between the return values and the arguments you could inspect the return values and do the logging in the calling function. Maybe use descriptors for data values  and design the descriptor to log when changed. Or Carcigenicate's  NamedData class could be designed to log when changed.

Answer (score 1):

Provided it makes sense for the data to be grouped, I'd group the name/data pairs in a structure. What you currently have is essentially ["parallel lists"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_array), which are typically a smell unless you're in a language where they're your only option.

A simple dataclass can be introduced:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class NamedData:
    name: str
    data: int
```

Then:

```
def function_to_log(pairs):
    pairs[3].data = 17.4
    log.info('You have changed {} to 17.4'.format(pairs[3].name))
    # and so on ...

return some_result_computed_from_list_of_numbers
```

As a sample of data:

```
pairs = [NamedData("Some Name", 1), NamedData("Some other name", 2)]
```

And if you have two separate lists, it's simple to adapt:

```
pairs = [NamedData(name, data) for name, data in zip(names, data_list)]
```

Only do this though if you typically need both bits in most places that each list is used. Grouping will only help clean up the code if the name and data are both needed in most places that either is used. Otherwise, you're just introducing overhead and bloat elsewhere to clean up a few calls.